# Modularity and plugability of Bootstrap themees

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There's a website I've been working on, building it with Grunt (not sure if that's useful information or not) and this Bootstrap framework that I got online.

At this point things are looking good content and layout wise and I didn't deviate at all from the Bootstrap conventions.

So now I'm thinking that I can simple find an alternative Bootstrap theme, download it and somehow hook it up to the content I have now and it should change the look and feel of the website whilst leaving everything else more or less the same- is that right?

If that is right- how to do it? Are there any good tutorials that explain how? I've been looking on Google- but I can't nail the keyword combination and I keep turning up pages upon pages of garbage results.

Does it have something to do with switching out the file `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Please narrow the question down to a specific issue/problem

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Yes, it is as simple as switching the css file.

Please take a look at [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com). They offer switchable bootstrap themes. It will give you a clear idea and some inspiration on how to work with this.

I stick to default Bootstrap and use Bootswatch for all my projects. Sometimes I use an extra css file called 'overrides.css' and I load it after the Bootstrap theme to do some custom styling.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about that css min file? what's that all about?

Comment: Same file, only shorter notation. Use that one instead of the .css file in production.

Comment: man- I tried this- but it didn't work :/

Comment: is there a way to use the inspect element thing to see which css file is being loaded?

Comment: That is an unrelated problem (loading the wrong CSS). If you post a new question, or use Google, you might get the answer.

Comment: it's a related question isn't it? why are you being so punctilious?

Comment: I am a programmer.